# Convertion of specific lines in a txt file

Tags: linux, awk

I am working on Linux and I have a text file which comprises these lines:

```
1 Q0 /home/nikol123/Downloads/metadata/12/119317.xml 1 -6.23956 indri  
1 Q0 /home/nikol123/Downloads/metadata/20/194709.xml 2 -6.47239 indri  
1 Q0 /home/nikol123/Downloads/metadata/13/120365.xml 3 -6.73307 indri  
2 Q0 /home/nikol123/Downloads/metadata/25/241886.xml 2 -6.53499 indri  
2 Q0 /home/nikol123/Downloads/metadata/18/175920.xml 3 -6.65065 indri
........
```

I want to convert it in order to take:

```
1 Q0 119317 1 -6.23956 indri  
1 Q0 194709 2 -6.47239 indri  
1 Q0 120365 3 -6.73307 indri
2 Q0 241886 2 -6.53499 indri  
2 Q0 175920 3 -6.65065 indri
........
```

I tried the awk command like this:

```
awk -F'[/ / / / / / . ]' '{print $1 " " $2 " " $9 " " $11 " " $12$13 " " $15}
```

but I get this result for the 1st line for example:

```
1 Q0 119317 1 -623956
```

So I wonder where is the decimal point in `-623956`? It should be `-6.23956`. And where is the word `indri`? Can you propose me a different syntax for the `awk` command?

Comment: If one of the answers, answers your question you could accept it by clicking the accept button.

Answer (score 1):

**sed**

```
sed -e 's|^\([0-9]\sQ0\).*/home.*/\(.*\).xml\s\(.*\)$|\1 \2 \3|' /path/to/file
```

**awk**

```
awk '{gsub(/\/home.*\/|.xml/, "")}; 1' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed answer to:

```
$ sed -E 's/\/[\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/|\.xml//g' file.txt
```

replace `file.txt` with the path to your file

Works on `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: He also need the field 3, but only the digit part before .xml, so your code is not a solution

Comment: ahh, sorry i didnt see that, for some reason.  ill try to fix

Answer (score 1):

```
nawk '{gsub(/\/home.*\//,"",$3); sub(".xml","",$3)}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up your `awk`, you can do this:

```
awk -F"[ /.]" '{print $1,$2,$9,$11,$12"."$13,$14}' file
1 Q0 119317 1 -6.23956 indri
1 Q0 194709 2 -6.47239 indri
1 Q0 120365 3 -6.73307 indri
2 Q0 241886 2 -6.53499 indri
2 Q0 175920 3 -6.65065 indri
```

The field separator within `[ ]` is telling to use one or another of the character used.
Your decimal point is gone since you are telling that it should be used as separator.